# Search criteria for identifier disappears

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, fhir-server-for-azure

We have a Microsoft FHIR solution in production and we have just upgraded to Build 20200512-3. We are running Microsoft FHIR server on Cosmos in Azure and we have just switched on autoscale, and the database just made a new partition.

After these events we have a problem that search on "identifier=|" disappears which means that instead of returning just one document, all documents are returned regardless of their identifier.

The search */Patient?_format=application/json&_pretty=true&identifier=&_total=accurate*

returns the following
    *{
      "relation": "self",
      "url": "https://hint.helsedirektoratet.no/kontaktregister/Patient?_format=application%2Fjson&_total=accurate"
    }*

As you can see the identifier has disappeared.
We have now had to close down our FHIR service and hardly any of our systems are working at the moment.

Please guide me if there are other channels I can use to reach Microsoft FHIR team faster than this.

Comment: The search string was inaccurate. Should be
The search /Patient?_format=application/json&_pretty=true&identifier=**socialsecuritynumber**&_total=accurate

The same happens to all other search criteria except "_id".

Comment: I am assuming this is the issue that is also on the Zulip chat and cross-posted as an issue on the FHIR server github repo. We will try to pick up the conversation on the gitub issue and to keep it in one place.